# Screen goes black for few seconds

Tags: 18.04, screen

I've got a problem. From time to time screen in my laptop just goes black for 3-5 sec, but I can still write, so system works well.

Someone can help?

HW: HP 840 G1

SW: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I have noticed it twice by last hour:
11:09 - black screen for 2 seconds,
11:47 - black screen for 3 seconds.

Log of first black screen:

```
perf: interrupt took too long (2510 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500 time was 11:08:58, then


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1669 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1669 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1669 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
```

11:09:46

And second 11:47:47 AM:

```
[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1669 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1669 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'


[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
```

and 11:47:50 AM

```
[session uid=1000 pid=1544] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
```